# Logic behind Google querying based on POI

Tags: google-app-engine, logic, latitude-longitude

I am Currently Working in Geocoding process based on google API service.Today my superior asked a question how does Google  exactly query a POI(Place Of Interest) if it is latitude and Longitude is passed.Can anyone help me in answering this?